# Categorise numeric vector in intervals, also including single values

Tags: r

I have a vector with numbers ranging from 0 to 1, both included. I would like to create a table with three categories: 0, (0, 1), 1. I have thought of using cut as follows:

```
# Example data
v <- c(0.68, 0.70, 0.95, 0.15, 0, 0.21, 0.14, 0, 1, 1)
# Table using cut
table(cut(v, c(-Inf, 0, 1, Inf)))
# Output
(-Inf,0]    (0,1] (1, Inf] 
       2        8        0
```

But I haven't figured out how to create a category for both "only 0" and "only 1" values at the same time. The desired result for this example would be:

```
# Desired output
(-Inf,0]    (0,1) [1, Inf) 
       2        6        2
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason to not just `table(cut(v, c(-Inf, 0, .999999999, Inf)))`

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just create your bins manually without `cut`?

```
v <- c(0.68, 0.70, 0.95, 0.15, 0, 0.21, 0.14, 0, 1, 1)

table(
  factor(
    ifelse(v == 0, "0", ifelse(v == 1, "1", "(0,1)")),
    levels = c("0", "(0,1)", "1")
  )
)
```

Output:

```
    0 (0,1)     1 
    2     6     2
```

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in the comments you can just make the cut-point more precise or for more control, `dplyr::case_when`

```r
v <- c(0.68, 0.70, 0.95, 0.15, 0, 0.21, 0.14, 0, 1, 1)

table(cut(v, c(-Inf, 0, .999999999, Inf)))
#> 
#> (-Inf,0]    (0,1] (1, Inf] 
#>        2        6        2

table(dplyr::case_when(v == 0 ~ "0",
                       v == 1 ~ "1",
                       TRUE ~ "> 0 & <1") %>% 
      factor())
#> 
#> > 0 & <1        0        1 
#>        6        2        2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with indexing of logical values:

```
#Data
v <- c(0.68, 0.70, 0.95, 0.15, 0, 0.21, 0.14, 0, 1, 1)
#Empty vector
vn <- rep(NA,length(v))
#Conditions
vn[which(v<=0)] <- '(-Inf,0]'
vn[which(v>=1)] <- '[1, Inf)'
vn[is.na(vn)]<-'(0-1)'
table(vn)
```

Output:

```
(-Inf,0]    (0-1) [1, Inf) 
       2        6        2
```